# JQuery function returns incorrect amount of pixels

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I have a webview that contains some js and jquery

var `viewport_top = $window.scrollTop()` is called within a function,

the problem is that this function returns an incorrect amount of pixels, i can see that from displaying an alert

My webview height is around 1600 pixels, when i scroll the height of my screen and call that function, it returns something around 500, which is like +- 1/3rd if what is should be

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i found the answer.

Appearantly pixels can have different sizes, i found out by calling window.devicePixelRatio

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily using jQuery or javscript.

**Method 1: Using jQuery**

```
$(window).height();
```

**Method 2:Using Javascript**

```
window.innerHeight
```